# what is the performance increase using the native elasticsearch client over rest?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does anyone know of any benchmarks of using the native Elasticsearch driver over the rest client? I'm specifically working with the Java client but any other language would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java then you can use native java client, which would be faster than HTTP Client. But if you are using any other language, then use REST Client would be faster, since client libraries in most programming languages use the HTTP Client themselves.

Comment: are there any benchmarks? i.e. is it 20%, 50% faster

Comment: It highly depends on the client implementation.https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-interfacing-elasticsearch-picking-client